# Propery injection not working with Prism Unity

Tags: dependency-injection, prism, unity-container

We have a WPF application using Prism (7.2.0.1422) and Unity as the DI container. I have the following class where I am attempting to use Unity Property injection

```
  public class LocalizedDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
  {
    [Dependency]
    IStringResource _stringResource { get; set; }
    string _resourceKey;
    public LocalizedDescriptionAttribute(string resourceKey)
    {
        _resourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            string description = _stringResource.GetString(_resourceKey);
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description) ? string.Format("[[{ 0}]]", _resourceKey) : description;
         }
      }
  }

   _stringResource  is always null. I have registered the type as a singleton like this in RegisterTypes

     containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IStringResource, StringResource>();
```

Anyone any ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the name of the class, I assume it's an actual attribute? That cannot have anything injected by `Unity`, because the container can only inject into instances it creates itself.

You can, however, use the container from the attribute's code through a detour: the `CommonServiceLocator`. That's a static class that you only use if you have to, and this may be one of the rare cases where it's a good idea. You can use it to resolve the `IStringResource` from the container at runtime.